Making tooltip top z-index
I am using Mantine-React-Table and I have an ActionIcon that I want to be on top layer, but by default is seems to get hidden by the length of the row. I want a tooltip or similar to appear when I hover over the action item. How can I do this?
I have set the z-index to a high value and it doesn't seem to work.

I was able to get the tooltip to show above the other elements of the table by adding the 'withinPortal' prop to the tooltip component and setting the zIndex to be higher than the elements surrounding it.  In my case I had to set it to 100.
https://v6.mantine.dev/core/tooltip/?t=props
Edit:  I made an assumption that you were using Mantine for the UI library.
